# How can I do this without resorting to the cycle FOR?

Tags: matlab

How can I do this without resorting to the cycle FOR?
MATLAB

= [1, 2, 3, 4]

```
L=Length(x);
for i=1:L
  if x(i)<0
      x(i)=-1;
  end
end
```

Comment: Use  [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/): `x(x<0) = -1;`

Comment: I'm not a programmer, so sorry for the basic question.

How is the complete code?

Comment: @lion that is the complete code!

Comment: This:

x(x<0) = -1;

Resumes this?

L=Length(x);
for i=1:L
  if x(i)<0
      x(i)=-1;
  end
end

Comment: @lion yes.  That's the power of logical indexing.  It is highly suggested you consult a basic MATLAB tutorial before asking more questions here.  Start with the matrices and arrays tutorials from MathWorks here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html?s_cid=learn_doc#responsive_offcanvas - They start off with basics such as array creation and go into more advanced topics, such as array indexing and logical indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for

```
x(x<0) = -1;
```

This way you avoid writing a loop. Actually, matlab runs an internal loop for you.